# The ReadElementContentAsString method is not supported on node type EndElement

Tags: c#, xml, winforms

I am trying to read xml file with XmlTextReader class my xml file is

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes'?>
<AppXmlLogWritter>
<LogData><LogID>999992013021213232800001</LogID><LogDateTime>20130212132328</LogDateTime><LogType>Message</LogType><LogFlag>Flag</LogFlag><LogApplication>Application</LogApplication><LogModule>Module</LogModule><LogLocation>Location</LogLocation><LogText>Text</LogText><LogStackTrace>Stacktrace</LogStackTrace></LogData>
</AppXmlLogWritter>
```

with the following code

```
FileStream fileStream = File.Open(txtBrowseFilePath.Text, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite);
             using (XmlTextReader objXmlReader = new XmlTextReader(fileStream))
{
                IEnumerable<LogData> data = LogData.GetLogData(objXmlReader);

                using(var item = data.GetEnumerator())
                {
                    while (item.MoveNext())
                    {
                        DataRow dataRow;
                        dataRow = dataTable.NewRow();

                        dataRow[0] = item.Current.LogID;
                        dataRow[1] = item.Current.LogDateTime;
                        dataRow[2] = item.Current.LogType;
                        dataRow[3] = item.Current.LogFlag;
                        dataRow[4] = item.Current.LogApplication;
                        dataRow[5] = item.Current.LogModule;
                        dataRow[6] = item.Current.LogLocation;
                        dataRow[7] = item.Current.LogText;
                        dataRow[8] = item.Current.LogStackTrace;

                        dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);
                    }
                }}
public static IEnumerable<LogData> GetLogData(XmlTextReader objXmlReader)
        {
            LogData objLogData = null;
            IXmlLineInfo xmlInfo = (IXmlLineInfo)objXmlReader;
            while(objXmlReader.Read())
            {


                if(objXmlReader.IsStartElement("LogData"))
                {
                    objLogData = new LogData();
                }
                if(objXmlReader.Name == "LogData" && objXmlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.EndElement)
                {
                    yield return objLogData;
                }
                if(objXmlReader.Name == "LogID")
                {
                    objLogData.LogID = objXmlReader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                }
                else if (objXmlReader.Name == "LogDateTime")
                {          
                    objLogData.LogDateTime = objXmlReader.ReadElementContentAsString();                   
                }
                else if(objXmlReader.Name == "LogType")
                {
                    objLogData.LogType = objXmlReader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                }
                else if(objXmlReader.Name == "LogFlag")
                {
                    objLogData.LogFlag = objXmlReader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                }
                else if(objXmlReader.Name == "LogApplication")
                {
                    objLogData.LogApplication = objXmlReader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                }
                else if(objXmlReader.Name == "LogModule")
                {
                    objLogData.LogModule = objXmlReader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                }
                else if(objXmlReader.Name == "LogLocation")
                {
                    objLogData.LogLocation = objXmlReader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                }
                else if(objXmlReader.Name == "LogText")
                {
                    objLogData.LogText = objXmlReader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                }
                else if(objXmlReader.Name == "LogStackTrace")
                {
                    objLogData.LogStackTrace = objXmlReader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                }
            }
        }
```

but it give me an error **"The ReadElementContentAsString method is not supported on node type EndElement "**
but when my xml file is as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<AppXmlLogWritter>
<LogData>
<LogID>999992013021110381000001</LogID>
<LogDateTime>20130211103810</LogDateTime>
<LogType>Message</LogType>
<LogFlag>Flag</LogFlag>
<LogApplication>Application</LogApplication>
<LogModule>Module</LogModule>
<LogLocation>Location</LogLocation>
<LogText>Text</LogText>
<LogStackTrace>Stacktrace</LogStackTrace>
</LogData>
</AppXmlLogWritter>
```

its work fine but i didnt get yet what actual problem with abouve xml file why it give me an error as i menstion. error occured at this line

```
 objLogData.LogDateTime = objXmlReader.ReadElementContentAsString();
```

Thnkx for ur reply

Comment: Which line is failing? Can you create a *short* but complete sample (with XML) of it failing? (I expect you only need a small fraction of the code you've shown in order to demonstrate the problem.)

Comment: error occured at this line  objLogData.LogDateTime = objXmlReader.ReadElementContentAsString();

Comment: Hmm. I know why it's failing, but that's not the error I'd have expected. I'd have expected it to report a node type of Text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the main cause of the problem is that you're using `ReadElementContentAsString` which moves the "cursor" to *after* the element you're reading - but you're then calling `Read()` again.

So when the XML data is like this:

```
<first>Foo</first><second>Bar</second>
```

... if you're positioned on the `first` element opening, then `ReadElementContentAsString` will move the reader onto the start of the `second` element. You then call `Read()` which moves into the text node ("Bar"). When you then call `ReadElementContentAsString` a second time, that will fail - because you're not on an element start node. However, I'd expect to get an exception of:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException:
The ReadElementContentAsString method is not supported on node type Text.
```

... whereas you've got a node type of `EndElement`, for some reason.

You should dig into exactly why that's happening (did you call `Read` manually while debugging, for example?) but the underlying problem you need to fix is calling `Read()` when you don't need to.

Comment: @srk: No, you can work it out for yourself. You need to think about exactly when you should be calling `Read()`, and when you shouldn't.

Comment: oh, teh irony, IMMORTAL laziness :)))

Answer (score 0):

You are using `IXmlLineInfo` and from the [msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.ixmllineinfo.aspx):

> Provides an interface to enable a class to return line and position
>   information.

which may be the cause of this error. I guess nothing is returned using `yield return` (since it is never called) and using `item.MoveNext()` results in `objXmlReader` move to the last element of the xml which results in an exception.

Note that, this is just a guess based on the data you have provided.